# Does the apache phoenix local index effective immediately after upsert?

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have a table created with local index, and then insert some  records using jdbc batch update according this [document](https://phoenix.apache.org/tuning_guide.html) about Writing section, finally i try to  retrieve records I created through sqlline.py,but I can't get the results .

1. create table with local index

   `CREATE TABLE test_table (
       id varchar primary key,
       fileName varchar,
       md5 varchar,
       hash varchar,
   ) SALT_BUCKETS = 5; 
   CREATE LOCAL INDEX test_table_index_md5 ON kodo_operation_log (md5);`
2. upsert records though jdbc api

   `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   int batchSize = 0;
   int commitSize = 1000; // number of rows you want to commit per 
    batch.

   try (Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(upsert)) {
     stmt.set ... while (there are records to upsert) {
       stmt.executeUpdate(); 
       batchSize++; 
       if (batchSize % commitSize == 0) { 
         conn.commit(); 
       } 
    } 
   conn.commit(); // commit the last batch of records 
   // query the record by index field ,but no records found
   }`
3. query the record through sqlline.py or jdbc api

   `select * from test_table where md5='138fde2b1c2a5bb7c6f7effebeedab76'`

but no rows found, my question is the local index doesn't effective immediately after upsert in same java thread?

Environment: 
phoenix 5.0.0-HBASE-2.0
HBASE 2.0.0

Comment: When I do another connection to retrieve the records, I actually get results in python driver code.